# Hovmoller plotting for netCDF data in python

Tags: python, plot, netcdf

I have 12 datasets of sea surface temperature from January to December. Datasets have 3 fields longitude, latitude, and sst.

I want to plot the hovmoller diagram in such a way that my y-axis represents latitude which ranges from 9 degrees North to 16 degrees North. whereas, the x-axis represents months which is from January to December.
And here the longitude will remain constant that is say 15.

I want python code for the same.

Here, is the sample image which I want
[image: img]

I am able to plot the data for the individual months using contourf function of matplotlib.

```
#Data for january-2019 to December-2019

months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]


for i in range(0,12):

data_file_name = "SST_" + months[i] + "_2019.nc"
local_file_path = 'C:/Users/hp/Desktop/ISRO/MODIS DATA NEW/'
local_file_path += data_file_name
file_handle = Dataset(local_file_path,mode = 'r', format ="NETCDF4")
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,8))

#Extracting all the columns from given .nc file
lat_scale = file_handle.variables['lat'][:] # 1D
lon_scale = file_handle.variables['lon'][:] # 1D
sst = file_handle.variables['sst'][:]

mBase2 = Basemap(llcrnrlon=50, llcrnrlat= 0, urcrnrlon= 100, urcrnrlat=27)
mBase2.drawmapboundary(color = 'green')
mBase2.drawcountries(linewidth = 2)
mBase2.drawcoastlines(linewidth = 2)
mBase2.drawparallels(np.arange(-90,90,5),labels=[True,False,False,False])
mBase2.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180,180,5),labels=[0,0,0,1])

v = np.linspace(22, 32, 50, endpoint=True)
mymap2 = plt.contourf(lon_scale, lat_scale, sst, v, cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar(mymap2, orientation = 'vertical')
title = "Sea Surface Temperature for " + months[i] + " - 2019"

plt.title(title)
image_name = str(i + 1) + "_SST_" + months[i] + "_2019"
plt.savefig(image_name)
```

For the above code, I got the following result for all 12 months.

[The above image is only for January, similarly, I got other images for 11 months.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Zmf.png)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Yes. I am sure someone is able to help on SO. But it is good behaviour to show first that you tried to solve the problem yourself

Comment: I am new to StackOverflow, sorry for asking for code directly.

Comment: I edited my question, In which I write down the code which I tried.